# Fail to start Hive queries(MapReduce)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have problems with hive queries. If i try to start *count(*)* query from hue interface but i get such exception:

```
15/01/23 15:06:42 ERROR operation.Operation: Error running hive query: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:147)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$000(SQLOperation.java:69)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:502)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

By starting same query in hive Cli i get:

```
hive> select count(*) from tweets; 
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:149)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:416)
    at com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString.toString(LiteralByteString.java:148)
    at com.google.protobuf.ByteString.toStringUtf8(ByteString.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.HdfsProtos$ExtendedBlockProto.getPoolId(HdfsProtos.java:743)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.convert(PBHelper.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:549)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getListing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.listPaths(DFSClient.java:1906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$15.<init>(DistributedFileSystem.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:525)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:517)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I tried to check logs in jobTracker but i get[image]

How cat solve all this errors?

- Cluster OS: CentOS 6.6
- Hadoop distro: Cloudera CDH 5.2
- Mapreduce: Yarn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood problem with

```
select count(*) from tweets;
```

The problem was that I placed my serde.jar in wrong directories on some Node-hosts. So i get errors with query in hive cli/Hue. CDH 4.* throws "Class not found Exception" and CDH 5.* Error code 2.

But problem with jobTracker(Yarn) is still present.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it worked in HiveCLI but not Beeline is because there is no user/group security enforced in HiveCLI, where as Beeline will adhere to some form of authorisation: Sentry/Ranger (if installed) or HDFS level permissions.